# Profile an application and check if reflection is used

Tags: reflection, .net-core, profiling, .net-standard

I would like to profile my application, and check if any part of my code is using reflection, but also if any part of the dotnet core or netstandard framework is using reflection during my application execution and usage.

The purpose of this exercise is to eventually detect reflexion usage at build time, at least reflection that is not put in a cache, but also try to improve the global performances of my webapi.

Thank you

Comment: What about a powershell script who search for "System.Reflection" in your *.cs files? you can add the script execution in your build pipeline (if you use TFS or similar) or at least in a post build event.

Comment: I would just profile everything and look for critical and slow paths in general. Do you have a reason to focus on reflection usage?